# Push notification to users after nth day

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification to user's on the second day after the event has occurred, any idea's how to achieve this.

I've created an audience for this and added user's to exclude group, but it seems to exclude all the users.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the above cannot be achieved on an event level.
I ended up using "Last app engagement" instead.[image]